# Flink: Unresolved compilation problem (valueOnly is not applicable for the arguments (Class<NumberDeserializers.IntegerDeserializer>))

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to setup a program where I can send a data stream with kafka to flink.

```
    DataStream<Integer> input =
            env.fromSource(
                    KafkaSource.<Integer>builder()
                            .setBootstrapServers(
                                    parameterTool
                                            .getProperties()
                                            .getProperty(
                                                    ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG))
                            .setBounded(OffsetsInitializer.latest())
                            .setDeserializer(
                                    KafkaRecordDeserializationSchema.valueOnly(
                                            IntegerDeserializer.class))
                            .setTopics(parameterTool.getRequired("input-topic"))
                            .build(),
                    WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(),
                    "kafka-source");
```

When I try to compile the code above the following failure occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method valueOnly(DeserializationSchema<V>) in the type KafkaRecordDeserializationSchema is not applicable for the arguments (Class<NumberDeserializers.IntegerDeserializer>)
```

There is a problem with the `valueOnly`, but I don't get what the problem is and how to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you picked up the wrong imports.

I think perhaps you wanted `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer` rather than the `IntegerDeserializer` from Jackson. The class you pass to `valueOnly` should implement `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I searched for such a long time, this was the issue... Now it's working :-)